# Add overlay while record video on Android

Tags: android, video, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

I want to record video by camera in my Android device. I need to add overlay image over recorded movie. In iOS I would use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). In Android I found [Android GPUImage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage). I tried to use it but I didn't found any way to add any filter while video recording. In provided example I could add filters only for taking photos. Is there any ways to record video with filters with [Android GPUImage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)? Is there any other ways to add images overlay over recording video in realtime? If not, is there any ways to add images overlay over recorded video in postprocessing?

Comment: If you want to add images in recorded video, there is a library call ffmpeg4android (http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html), which may help you to do this. Following, you can find all command syntax here https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html. Hope it is not too late

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overlay image on video using a blend filter.

About video recording: android-gpuimage library does not support it but you can try using the android-gpuimage-videorecording library. It is a fork of the gpu-image for android that provides also the video recording functionality

[android-gpuimage-videorecording](https://github.com/westbrett/android-gpuimage-videorecording)

see the GPUImageMovieWriter class

It should point you in the right direction for developing your own video writer on top of GPUImage.

The idea is to:

- draw on current screen surface
- switch to encoder input surface and draw previous frame buffer again on it
- switch back to screen surface

other useful links: [EGL surface helper](https://github.com/google/grafika), [Media encoder](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)

Answer (score 0):

This project ([MagicCamera](https://github.com/wuhaoyu1990/MagicCamera)) has many multiple input filters. You can write your own fragment shader to overlay an image on camera texture (similar to MagicN1977Filter). It also includes video recording.