# Android - Add text or image while recording video?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

I am struggling with recording and editing videos. For editing, I found a useful library in Android named [ffmpeg4Android](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html). However, I am still get stuck in recording video. Here is what I want:

1/ Add text or images in video while recording
2/ Add filter while recording video

I found there is a library [GPUImage for Android](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) but it has only some examples related to taking a photo, not to recording video)

Please let me know if you have any ways or any suggested libraries which can do it.

Thank you in advance!

Links which I read when researching:
[Add overlay while record video on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703326/add-overlay-while-record-video-on-android) 
[How to Record video with GPUImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467726/how-to-record-video-with-gpuimage) 
[FFMpeg add text to actual video file after recording in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532269/ffmpeg-add-text-to-actual-video-file-after-recording-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add text to the video in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641280/how-to-add-text-to-the-video-in-android)

Comment: @Fattie: My question is not duplicate. I want to "add text to video WHILE recording". Your link is "add text AFTER recording". Thank you for helping me Fattie :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overlay image on video using a blend filter.

You cannot add text directly but you can add the text to the image writing on a canvas.

android-gpuimage library does not natively support video recording but you can try using the android-gpuimage-videorecording library. It is a fork of the gpu-image for android that provides also the video recording functionality

[android-gpuimage-videorecording](https://github.com/westbrett/android-gpuimage-videorecording)

see the GPUImageMovieWriter class

It should point you in the right direction for developing your own video writer on top of GPUImage.

The idea is to:

- draw on current screen surface
- switch to encoder input surface and draw previous frame buffer again on it
- switch back to screen surface

other useful links: [EGL surface helper](https://github.com/google/grafika), [Media encoder](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)